# How to get actual time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get the actual time in java script to make an online clock?

```
var dt=new Date();
hr=dt.getHours();
```

this will give the time. But its depend on the time in our computer.
I need the server time.
anybody can help me...
Thanks.

Comment: You mean you don't want the time from the users computer. So your looking for [getting server time](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+server+time+javascript). A question that is pretty thoroughly popular here.

Comment: If not your time then whose time?

Comment: Sent me a request or call me helpline 121. I will give you the time (Man javascript is client side programming - except note.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide a time service and using an asynchronous request to get that time - see the example by James Padolsey [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/getting-the-real-time-in-javascript/):

```
function getTime(zone, success) {
    var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=' + zone,
        ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
    window[ud]= function(o){
        success && success(new Date(o.datetime), o);
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild((function(){
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = url + '&callback=' + ud;
        return s;
    })());
}
```

This can be acheived in many ways, but basically what you need to do is provide a small dynamic page which prints your server's time (JSON would be a nicer approach) using PHP or any other dynamic approach and call it using AJAX in your web page as shown in James' example where the URL is your new dynamic time page.

Comment: Good job putting the code here. I was nearly done editing your post with the sample when you did it too! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a server side program which prints the current time of the server (or as per your requirement) in PHP or ASP as below: (Just an example).

```
<?php
echo date("l M dS, Y, H:i:s");
?>
```

Then just request that page using AJAX and display in your page or do whatever with that response.

Answer (score -1):

Look Getting time in javascript is not a big deal but it will give you time according to the local machine of client it can be different from the current running time....

The best solution for it is getting time from server side using ajax and using server side function such as date and time function.

For more info please see this link:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php